# django convert sql CREATE query to model

Tags: django

I have several sql **CREATE** querys.How do I create models for them(not manually).

Comment: I got the answer [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789191/django-import-tables-as-models)

Comment: Jibins link holds the answer to your question.

Comment: I'm sure Jibin knows that Jibins link holds the answer :D

Comment: Unfortunately not all database adapters have introspection support built in.  Like the django-sqlany adapter.  Dumping a "CREATE TABLE" statement into a utility to create a model would be seriously handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789191/django-import-tables-as-models)

I got the answer to my question(as mentioned in my comment). But I is was reviewing of my stalkoverflow profile and I saw this question unanswered and unclosed.So have pasted the link to the answer once again.